# Whats the best way to install nodejs in different location

Tags: windows, node.js, macos

By default nodejs is installed in `/usr/local/bin/node` but this location needs root access rights.

If I then install a global package like grunt-cli or a yeoman generator they also need root access rights. But I don't want to install all global packages with sudo.

So I tought why not install node and its global packages under something like `opt/bin/node` for example and give this location user access rights.

I used to download the installer from the nodejs website but with that I can't change location of the installation. So the question is:

**How can I install nodejs in a differnt location than the default location on OSX and Windows?**

Answer (score 1):

Search engines are your friend.

Taken directly from the [node docs](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#installing-on-windows):

> #### On Windows
>
> The http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ directory contains executables of
> the last version of Node.js engine (the engine only, i.e. without
> npm):
>
> 32bit version: http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node.exe
>
> 64bit version: http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/x64/node.exe
>
> The http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/ directory contains the latest .zip
> archive of npm (such as npm-1.1.16.zip when npm v1.1.16 was the
> latest).
>
> #### Manual installation steps:
>
> 1. Make a clean directory and add that directory to your system's PATH variable.
> 2. Download the latest node.exe to that directory.
> 3. Download the latest npm's .zip file and unpack its contents to the same directory.
>
> Then, with the usual help of PATH, you'll be able to run scripts (node
> scriptname.js) and install modules (npm install modulename) in any
> directory.

...and just below that...

> #### Installing on Mac
>
> The http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/ directory contains the latest .pkg
> package (such as node-v0.6.15.pkg when Node v0.6.15 was the latest).

Comment: I used the package before but with that you cannot change the path to something like `opt/bin/node`. Maybe building it myself and then set the new path with ./configure could work?

Comment: If your only concern is the location of globally installed npm packages, maybe look at configuring npm instead of changing the location?  I know this side-steps your question, but `npm config` and the corresponding functionality mean you get a default node/npm install AND avoid having to run anything as root/sudo/admin.

Answer (score 1):

we have discussed your issue with some unix guru´s.

in UNIX / MAC:
we believe the best way to install a node package "global" *(non-project-specific respectively in your user environment)* is to install node in folder
**/opt/node or /home/user/.node** and change the user-right, as you mentioned.

we believe its the wrong way, to change the /usr/ folder-rights or install global-packages with sudo.

in my case, i think the solution to change npm-config *(mentioned in many other stackoverflow topics)* did not changed anything, because node is still installed in /usr/bin.

still we belief, as a developer its more recommended to build such frequently updated  applications like node by yourself instead of using the unix package manager. because mostly the resources ain't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm.  It's a version manager for node, but one of the best parts of it (for me) is that it installs each version of node in your home directory.  This means that your npm global install is also in this home directory.  It's a Mac/Unix solution.

For Windows, though I've never tried it, there is the (similar) nvmw project: https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw.